# How to render template from text?

Tags: twig, symfony-2.8

I want to store in my database a large text from an HTML file that could have Twig directives such as double curly braces, pipes, etc. From that string, I want to render a Twig template and send it back to the client.

```php
public function renderAction (Request $request) {
    $text = "<!doctype html>
        <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            {{SomeVariable}}
        </body>
        </html>";
    $template = $this->render($text, $parameters);

    return new JsonResponse(["status" => "ok", "template" => $template], 200);
}
```

When I try this I got an error, it seems like the first param from `$this->render` is always used as a path to a twig file but I will not be storing URI but the HTML file content in my database. Is there any way to render a twig template from a string?

I also tried using

```php
$template = $this->get('twig')->createTemplate($text);

return new JsonResponse(["status" => "ok", "template" => $template], 200);
```

but the "template" prop is always empty when the client receives it

I am using Symfony 2.8.52 and PHP 5.6

Comment: `->createTemplate($text)` is a good start. `->createTemplate($text)->render($parameters)` is even better. see functions on a *template*: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/2.x/src/TemplateWrapper.php#L41 please note though, that this doesn't use the cache that's usually used for templates.

Comment: @Jakumi The link is pretty useless and another example for Symfony's inferiority with regards to providing useful documentation. Listed methods are "described" with up to 5 words repeating what is deducible from the name of either method's name already ...